# how to apply a method to a variable stored in other file in python?

Tags: python, selenium, oop, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have two files, **test_e2e.py** and **CheckOutPage.py**. There is a method '**getProducts()**' in **CheckOutPage.py** which returns a list of all the elements having particular xpath. This list is returned to a variable '**products**' which is in **test_e2epage.py**. Now, I am traversing through the '**products**' list and trying to apply a method '**getProductName()**' which is present **CheckOutPage.py**, but I am unable to do so. The code is below.

CheckOutPage.py-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class CheckOutPage:

    def __init__(self, driver):  #Constructor
        self.driver = driver

    products = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card h-100']")
    productName = (By.XPATH, "div/h4/a")

    def getProducts(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements(*CheckOutPage.products)

    def getProductName(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*CheckOutPage.productName)
```

test_e2e.py-

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
from pageObjects.CheckOutPage import CheckOutPage
from pageObjects.HomePage import HomePage
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_e2e(self):

        # Select only Blackberry.
        checkOutPage = CheckOutPage(self.driver)
        products = checkOutPage.getProducts()
        for product in products:
            #productName = product.find_element_by_xpath("div/h4/a").text
            Name = product.checkOutPage.getProductName()
            if Name == "Blackberry":
                product.checkOutPage.selectProduct().click()
                break
```

The code is failing on third line of for loop in test_e2e.py.
The error is "**AttributeError: 'webElement' object has no attribute 'checkoutPage'**". Please help me guys. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through web elements returned by CheckOutPage, they are not methods returned by CheckOutPage. Here is how I would have written it

```
class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_e2e(self):

        # Select only Blackberry.
        checkOutPage = CheckOutPage(self.driver)
        products = checkOutPage.getProducts()
        for product in products:
            #productName = product.find_element_by_xpath("div/h4/a").text
            Name = checkOutPage.getProductName(product)
            if Name == "Blackberry":
                product.checkOutPage.selectProduct().click()
                break

class CheckOutPage:

    def __init__(self, driver):  #Constructor
        self.driver = driver

    products = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card h-100']")
    productName = (By.XPATH, "div/h4/a")

    def getProducts(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements(*CheckOutPage.products)

    def getProductName(self, product):
        return self.driver.find_element(*CheckOutPage.productName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Name = product.checkOutPage.getProductName()
```

This line in the the loop attempts to access an attribute `checkOutPage` from the `product` object which is a Selenium [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) object and not a `CheckOutPage` object. It has no such attribute.